# Which group is more ortho/para-directing?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, hyperconjugation, aldol-reaction

Currently working on assigning the C NMR and H NMR spectra for this molecule *(I believe it's called E-E bis(4-methylbenzylidene)acetone )* but I'm a bit confused as to whether the methyl group is more or less activating than the R-group (labelled in image).

Since alkyl groups are directing via hyperconjugation I thought that methyl group would be more activating of the ortho and para positions as it has more C-H σ bonds to donate to a potential empty p-orbital.

**If this is the case, are the carbons in position 3 less deshielded than in position 4 so would show a lower chemical shift in NMR spectra?**

*If I'm being honest I don't think understand how alkyl groups are activating, I was just told that they were and was given a vague description on how they are activating but I can't seem to apply it to different scenarios. I've searched online for different explanations but none quite click with me.*
[image]

Comment: Central group is deactivating, just like analogous formyl.